# Server query to find the current designation of the employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Table Employee:

```
ID, Designation, PromotionDate
```

Code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetTheDesignationEmployee
    (@EmpID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Designation VARCHAR(25) = ''

    SELECT @Designation = Designation  
    FROM Employee
    WHERE PromotionDate = (SELECT MAX(PromotionDate) 
                           FROM Employee
                           WHERE ID = @EmpID)

    RETURN(@Designation)
END
```

If I run the code, I should get the current designation of the employee. I pass the ID, and should get back the corresponding current designation.

```
SELECT dbo.GetTheDesignationEmployee(5346)
```

But I get an error instead of an answer.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting the current designation of the employee... i dont know how to achieve that using function

Comment: That's a symptom. You say you get errors, I presume that to mean SSMS is returning an error(s) that specifically references the heart of the issue. What does that error(s) say?

Comment: *"Im not getting the current designation of the employee."* but in the question you state *"But I get an error instead of an answer."* Are you therefore *not* getting an error? If so, why state you are, and what *is* happening? If you *are* getting an error, then what is that error?

Comment: i get the answer but not the correct answer. im getting some Designation. not the current Designation. its for displaying the Current Designation when we enter an Employee ID .Employee may get promotions in different dates .so we want to find the current designation

Comment: *"i get the answer but not the correct answer. "* Then you ***aren't*** getting an error, so why tell us you are?

Comment: Also, why does the function return a `varchar(MAX)` when `@Designation` (which is what you `RETURN`) is defined as a `varchar(25)`? What are the other 2GB-25bytes (2,147,483,623bytes) for?

Comment: Its Solved. Got the answer . There was 1 more condition to be added . Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most likely**; if I interpret your last comment correctly, you're getting a designation with a proper date - but since you've **forgot** to limit the outer `SELECT` to use the `@EmpID` passed it, it might be someone else's (with the same `PromotionDate`)....

Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetTheDesignationEmployee
    (@EmpID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Designation VARCHAR(25) = ''

    SELECT @Designation = Designation  
    FROM EmployeeDetails 
    WHERE PromotionDate = (SELECT MAX(PromotionDate) 
                           FROM EmployeeDetails 
                           WHERE ID = @EmpID)
      -- you need to also include the @EmpID here!
      AND ID = @EmpID;

    RETURN(@Designation)
END
```

Or you could write the whole function much simpler:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetTheDesignationEmployee
    (@EmpID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Designation VARCHAR(25) = ''

    SELECT TOP (1) @Designation = Designation  
    FROM EmployeeDetails 
    WHERE ID = @EmpID
    ORDER BY PromotionDate DESC;

    RETURN(@Designation)
END
```

**WORD of warning:** scalar functions that are doing data access are notoriously bad for performance - so maybe you want to think about another way to get that "most recent designation" in your query to avoid having to write and use this function in the first place.